# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'details' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried:

Tags: django

I can't seem to spot the error in my code and I have tried everything. It is probably something simple that is escaping my eye. Please help! Any imput is appreciated. New Django learner here.

```
    #views.py 
    def details(self, Testimony_id):
        Testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk= Testimony_id)
        return render(request, 'details.html', {'Testimony': Testimony})


    #template
    <header class="w3-container w3-blue">
        <h1><a href="{% url 'Testimony:details' Testimony.id %}">{{Testimony.Title}}</h1>
     </header>


    #urls.py
    app_name='Testimony
    urlpattern=[
    ...
    re_path('<int:id>/', views.detail, name='details'),]


    #models.py
    class Testimony(models.Model):
    ...

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Testimony.objects.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

#forms.py
class TestimonyForm(forms.Form):
    body = forms.CharField(label='Details', widget=forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is you url path looks id but function parameter Testimony_id.

Change like this.

```
re_path('<int:Testimony_id>/', views.detail, name='details'),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change it to be

## views.py

```
def details(self, pk):
    testimony=get_object_or_404(Testimony, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'details.html', {'testimony': testimony})
```

## template

```
<header class="w3-container w3-blue">
    <h1><a href="{% url 'Testimony:details' pk=testimony.id %}">{{testimony.Title}}</h1>
 </header>
```

## urls.py

```
urlpattern=[
...
re_path('<int:pk>/', views.detail, name='details'),]
```

And it will work.

Comment: Now it shows: Reverse for 'details' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['<int:pk>\\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$', '<int:pk>/']